# What time period did the Engineer disintegrate himself on Earth?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

I was unclear if the Engineer who drinks the black liquid and disintegrates at the beginning of Prometheus seeded life or just human life -- was there any indication of *when* in time that part happened?

Comment: There is just no evidence whatsoever if the engineer disintegrated himself on planet earth or some another planet in the infinite space. You can read more here. http://io9.com/5917448/all-of-your-lingering-prometheus-questions-answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made the same mistake of presuming it happened on earth. But you never know. Prometheus writer shares his views here and clarifies the same.
http://io9.com/5917448/all-of-your-lingering-prometheus-questions-answered

Comment: Good to know that it could be anywhere, showing that the Engineers performed this ritual on many planets. But [the Blu-Ray disc states that it *is* Earth](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24674/3430) which somewhat contradicts what Ridley Scott says here...

Answer (score 11):

**1-3 billion years ago, give or take. From the initial flyover, we see low level photosynthesis going on, but no trees, no flowers, and no animals. [Life on Earth, an evolutionary timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_evolutionary_history_of_life).**

[image: Life on Earth, an evolutionary timeline]

If the Engineers were considering seeding the planet with animal DNA, this would be a good time to get into the game, providing their black mutagen and themselves as the source DNA to build toward the development of multi-cellular life. Since Humanity shared a match of a significant series of DNA structures, it can be assumed, their mutagen was designed to ensure the eventual recreation of structures similar, and I suspect hopefully better versions of the Engineers.

It has also been hinted that the planet we are looking at in the flyover is not necessarily Earth but one of many planets the seed-bearing Engineers may have seeded in a similar manner as they are believed to have done on Earth.

Comment: Wasn't there a Star Trek episode with a similar concept?

Comment: Also, I was not sure whether the flyover was a good indication, since it could have just been Arctic tundra or something... still, that may be our only clue

Comment: Yes, we know it was an Arctic tundra somewhere on present day Earth. The goal was to make us believe it was in the distant past on an Earth ready for multicellular life and just needing a genetic jumpstart.

Comment: @zipquincy The Star Trek episode was called [The Chase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chase_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))

Comment: I recall seing mentions of the trees in some of the discussions of the topic.